# How to select a java.util.List of objects using a mybatis resultMap association and select

Tags: java, mybatis

I have this almost working.

```
<mapper namespace="com.xyz.rb.dao.RBCellDao">
    <resultMap id="rbCellResultMap" type="com.xyz.rb.model.RBCell">
        <id property="id" column="id" />
        <result property="fieldIds" column="fieldIds" typeHandler="com.xyz.dao.typehandlers.CommaSeparatedLongListTypeHandler" />
        <association property="fields" column="fieldIds" javaType="java.util.List" select="selectFields"></association>
    </resultMap>

    <select id="selectFields" parameterType="String" resultType="com.xyz.abc.model.Field">
        SELECT * FROM fields WHERE id IN (#{value}) <!-- this appears to get the correct value ====> Parameters: 1,2,3(String) -->
    </select>
</mapper>
```

RBCell Table data looks like:

```
| ID | FIELDIDS      |  
|  1 | 1,2,3         | 
|  2 | 45,54321,9,78 |
```

This is returning a List as expect, HOWEVER, there is only ever one entry in the List no matter what value is in the FieldIds column...

What am I missing here?  How can I get this to return the entire list of Field instead of what appears to be only the first one?

Answer (score 0):

Between main query and associated query, the parameter is string exactly. So use parameter in associated query just like this:

```
SELECT * FROM fields WHERE id IN ('1,2,3');
```

if you want do the `in` thing, assumed you used mysql, you can try `find_in_set`:

```
SELECT * FROM fields WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, #{value});
```

Else, you can try `like` to do this.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond to my question.  I don't believe the issue is with the query.  The query appears to work fine.  The issue I think is in how Mybatis is configured using the resultMap and association tag.  That said, I am already using the parameter exactly as you described in your first SQL.

Comment: Nope, you've misunderstood my elaboration, the first query just wants to explain how your query works, not my solution, second one is the way I want to solve the problem. Of course, the answer you metioned below works as well. @kasdega

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being simply to change:

SELECT * FROM fields WHERE id IN (#{value})
to
SELECT * FROM fields WHERE id IN (${value})

It works now.